# The 'Pods-{Some Target}' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (Flipper-Boost-iOSX and Flipper-RSocket)-Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

Following the [tutorial](https://rnfirebase.io/) to install React Native Firebase package.

**I am constantly getting this error:-**

> `The 'Pods-{Some Target}' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (Flipper-Boost-iOSX and Flipper-RSocket)`.

I haven't found the concrete solution to this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is pretty obvious based on the error message we are getting, but 'I am web developer, why would I bother with Pods :D'.
Commenting out this line: `:flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled` should do the trick, at least it worked for me.

Let me post here the whole `Pods` file:

```html
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.4'
install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

production = ENV["PRODUCTION"] == "1"

target 'RNComponents' do

  use_frameworks!
  config = use_native_modules!

  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :production => production,
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'RNComponentsTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

Comment: Should I be concerned about commenting out :flipper_configuration => FlipperConfiguration.enabled - why does it have to be commented out?

Answer (score 1):

comment out

```
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_Flipper()
```

probably somewhere line 27 in ios/podfile