# The target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (Flipper-Boost-iOSX and Flipper-RSocket)

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

hi i want to use firebase i tried to follow the instructions without success

[i follow](https://rnfirebase.io/)

when i using command `pod install`

error type :[!] The 'Pods-Coffee' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (Flipper-Boost-iOSX and Flipper-RSocket)

Podfile

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

# add
$RNFirebaseAnalyticsWithoutAdIdSupport = true # Disable Ad Id usage
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
# end

flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Coffee' do
  config = use_native_modules!

#add
 use_frameworks!
# end




  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    # Upcoming versions of React Native may rely on get_default_flags(), but
    # we make it explicit here to aid in the React Native upgrade process.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

  target 'CoffeeTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      # Set `mac_catalyst_enabled` to `true` in order to apply patches
      # necessary for Mac Catalyst builds
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

[I tried to do it this way without success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73533902/the-pods-some-target-target-has-transitive-dependencies-that-include-statica)